# show capture result before data capture

Tags: smarty

Is it possible to display the captured content of a div at the top of a page when the actual div is in the middle?

I tried using capture but as the content div is after where I need to display the value it doesn't seem to work

e.g

```
...some content
{$smarty.capture.divlink}
...some more content
<div class="capture_content">
    {capture name="divlink"}
        Content I need to display
    {/capture}
</div>
...some more content
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually there's no point in putting the `{capture}` inside the `<div>`, you can put it anywhere you want:

```
{capture name="divlink"}
    Content I need to display
{/capture}
...some content
{$smarty.capture.divlink}
...some more content
<div class="capture_content">
    What do you want to display here?
</div>
...some more content
```

Comment: Sorry may not have been clear but the content I need to capture is created dynamically within the capture_content `<div>`. So the Content I need to display is whatever is generated and rendered in the capture_content `<div>` so I cant assign anything to the capture before the `<div>` and the output from the capture needs to be before the `<div>`

Comment: Where does this content come from? If it's generated server side, you can put it where you want in the template. If it's generated client side / read by ajax, the template has already been parsed, so you can't use smarty for this.

Comment: Thanks I used `{debug}` to find the variable that contained the data and referenced it that way